# How to use python .concat to add web scrape text to DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

Please someone show me how to add my results( address,distance etc) into my london_data dataframe
i am stuck here

```
london_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Address', 'Bedrooms', 'Distance', 'Date Listed', 'Rent'])

for row in soup.find('div', class_='css-1itfubx e19tytbu0').find_all('div', class_='e19tytbu1 css-1x0ju0p esqwi9k19'):
    address = row.find('p', class_='css-5agpw4 esqwi9k33').text
    bedrooms = row.find('p', class_='css-r8a2xt-Text eczcs4p0').text
    distance = row.find('p', class_='css-nwapgq-Text eczcs4p0').text
    date_listed = row.find('span', class_='css-dwkus2 esqwi9k34').text
    rent = row.find('p', class_='css-1w7anck esqwi9k31').text.strip(' pcm').strip('£')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
london_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Address": pd.Series(adress),
        "Bedrooms": pd.Series(bedrooms),
        "Distance": pd.Series(distance),
        "Date Listed": pd.Series(date_listed),
        "Rent": pd.Series(rent),
    }
)
```

No need in defining the df with columns only before.
`pd.Series` is only needed in case your scraped data has different length